# How to print preprocess_html variables in page.tpl

Tags: theming

I have variable in template.php to use in different files like page.tpl, but written this in preprocess_html function as below, how can i print this in page.tpl and html.tpl file.

```
mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables){
      $variables['xyz'] = $xyz;
}
```

In page.tpl file, I tried with `print $xyz;` but it is not printing, where as I can able to print in html.tpl file this variable. Initially tried to add my code in preproces_page function, but I can't able to get in html.tpl file in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another, perhaps simpler, to add variables to multiple templates, is too use an earlier [`hook_preprocess`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7)

> Preprocess theme variables for templates.
>   This preprocess function is the first in the sequence of preprocessing and processing functions that is called when preparing variables for a template.

```
e.g:

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess
 * @param $variables
 *   The variables array by reference.
 * @param $hook
 *   The name of the theme hook.
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  switch($hook){
    case 'html':
    case 'page':
      $variables['foo'] = 'my special variable';
    break;
  }
}
```

See also: [`template_preprocess`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7)

Answer (score 1):

Variables added to template_preprocess_html are available in html.tpl.php

`mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables){
  $variables['xyz'] = $xyz;
}`

And variables added to template_preprocess_page are available in page.tpl.php

`mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables){
  $variables['xyz'] = $xyz;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Not really a Drupal question, but

```
function MYTHEME_some_function() {
  return 'bar';
}

function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['foo'] = MYTHEME_some_function();
}

function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['foo'] = MYTHEME_some_function();
}
```